# Upsampling data in matlab gives a "drift" in the data

Tags: matlab

I have 2 signals, one of them has a sampling rate of 500 Hz and the other has a sampling rate of (about, and not exactly) 115 Hz. I need to upsample the 115 Hz signal to detect events in the 500 Hz signal, but there seems to be a drift in the data. To make this clearer, I have an event that I can detect easily in the 500 Hz signal and in the 115 Hz as well, but the position of the marker (in the 115 Hz) relatively to the actual event in the 500 Hz signal, after upsampling, changes throughout the whole signal. My code looks like this:

```
counter = 1;

for i = 1:length(time)
    position = round(time(i)*fs);
    if position ~= 0 && position <= size(data,1)
        convertedData(i,:) = data(position,:);
    elseif position > size(data,1)
        convertedData(i,:) = data(size(data,1),:);
    else
        convertedData(i,:) = data(1,:);        
    end
end
```

Note: I do not need to interpolate points since it doesn't matter when exactly the marker is placed, as long as it is always place in the same position relatively to the event in the 500 Hz signal. In the code above, 'time' is an array with the same number of elements as the 500 Hz signal (from 0 to the end of the signal), 'fs' is the sampling frequency of the marker signal (around 115 Hz), 'data' is the marker signal.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Looks like a problem with MATLAB's 1-based indexing.

Comment: Even though you say you don't need to interpolate the points, wouldn't it be better to resample the data (after converting it to a `timeseries` object) to compare it?
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.resample.html

Comment: @PaulR could you explain further? Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I'm guessing it might need to be: `position = 1 + round(time(i)*fs);` ?

Comment: @am304, I cannot use the 'resample' function because my sampling frequency of the 115 Hz signal is not reliable, when I calculate it with Matlab it doesn't return an integer value but something like 114.999. I tried the resample function with 115 and I get less data points than I need...

Comment: @PaulR, thanks a lot, this solved my problem, would you care to post an explanation as an actual answer so I can close down the question as "solved"? Thank you again!

Comment: @PL-RL: no problem - glad it worked out - I've posted my comments as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common problem with working with MATLAB is that all vectors, matrices, etc use 1-based indexing, rather than the more natural 0-based indexing that is typically used in maths, engineering, DSP, etc. In your particular case the calculation for `position` needs to be changed from:

```
    position = round(time(i)*fs);
```

to:

```
    position = 1 + round(time(i)*fs);
```

to get the correct correspondence between time and (1-based) sample number.